# Selecionar todos checkbox ao clicar em um checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Procurei a solução aqui no fórum, entretanto as mesmas não funcionaram.

Quero selecionar todos os `checkbox` ao clicar em apenas 1 `checkbox` (seleciona todos).

**Segue meu  código:**

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min.css">

    <meta name="description" content="Violate Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Super Admin, Admin, Template, Bootstrap">

     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
          //Para fins de depuração:
          console.log("Entrei aqui.");
            $("#checkMaster").click(function(){
            //Para fins de depuração:
            console.log("Checkbox mestre foi clicado!");    
                $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
            });
            console.log("saiu aqui.");
        });

    </script>

<!--    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" /> -->
  </head>
```

Warning

```
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">


                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="data-table" class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>Telefone</th>
                                    <th>Numero de tentativas</th>
                                    <th>Ultima Tentativa</th>
                                    <th>Zerar Tentativas?</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><p><input type="checkbox" id="checkMaster" name="checkTodos"> Selecionar Todos</p></td>

                                </tr>
                                <?php 

                                    $query = sprintf("select * from ivr_contatos, ivr_campanha where ivr_contatos.campanha = ivr_campanha.id and ivr_contatos.status = 0 and tentativas >= 5" );
                                    $result = Populator::ConsultaDB($query);

                                    while ($resultado = pg_fetch_array($result) ) {
                                        $nome = $resultado['nome'];
                                        $telefone = $resultado['telefone'];
                                        $tentativa = $resultado['tentativas'];
                                        $lastAttempt = $resultado['atualizado'];
                                        $codigo = $resultado['codigo'];

                               echo '         

                                <tr>
                                    <td>'.$nome.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$telefone.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$tentativa.'</td>
                                    <td>'.substr($lastAttempt,0,19).'</td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" value='.$codigo.' name="check[]"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                ';
                                    }
                                ?>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Resubmit" class="btn btn-sm m-r-5" />

        </form>
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver isso??

Edit: Caros, boa tarde, realizei as recomendações deste post, entretanto ainda estou com o mesmo problema. Há mais algum caminho que eu possa seguir para atingir este objetivo?

Segue print do console:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
init(16) [input#ckball, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, prevObject: init(16), context: document]
```

Comment: O código me parece ok! O que não está funcionando?

Comment: Quando clico no checkbox selecionar todos, os outros não são marcados como checked

Comment: O seu código está funcionando, veja aqui https://jsfiddle.net/Lwamk47c/

Comment: Tenta colocar o código dentro de `$(document).ready(function(){  código aqui });`

Comment: Tentei, mas tbm não rolou, eu to encucado com isso cara, no jsfiddle funciona, na pagina web não...

Comment: Veja se mostra erro no console ao clicar o checkbox chefe

Comment: No console esta mostrando erro nesta linha   
  $('input:checkbox').(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
mostra este erro, mas não to conseguindo localizar.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: Esse `.(this)` está errado... o correto é `$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);`

Comment: Realizei a alteração, o erro no console sumiu, mas ainda não seleciona os demais checkbox

Comment: Tem certeza que só existe 1 id com "checkTodos"?

Comment: vai no console e executa `$("#checkTodos").length`... se retornar mais de 1 aí é ruim

Comment: Executei, ele retornou só 1

Comment: Então a única saída é vc mostrar o código todo, apenas da parte que envolve o javascript e a tabela.

Comment: postei na resposta.

Comment: Com o `$(document).ready(function(){` funcionou

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#checkTodos").click(function(){
         $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        });`

Comment: Realizei a alteração, entretanto persiste... Talvez, o bootstrap esconda quando as outras são checadas? ou não teria influencia?

Comment: Caique, realizei os testes, e ele devolve a seguinte informação para console.log( $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked') );  = false; 
        
console.log( $('input:checkbox').not(this) );
VM2617:1 init(16) [input#ckball, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, input#ckbCod.check, prevObject: init(16), context: document]

Comment: @CaiqueRomero então, a questão do ID é que como esse checkbox é gerado sempre que é feito um novo registro no banco.

Comment: Você colocou fixo `<td><input type='checkbox' id='ckbCod'></td>` isso está dentro de um loop, portanto, seu html conterá vários `<input />` com mesmo `id` entende?

Comment: Sim.. mas isso seria uma necessidade da aplicação pq sempre que existir um registro no banco seria criado um checkbox para ele. Não existe forma de eu selecionar todos os checkbox mesmo com o mesmo ID? ou criar um ID dinamico?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero ele chega a rodar, vou colocar na pergunta para vc ver a resposta

Comment: pelo console ele mostra que esta como checked, mas visualmente não aparece

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77706/discussion-between-caique-romero-and-willian-lima).

Answer (score 1):

Só mudar essa linha:

```
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

Olha aí:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/145709/

Comment: Ainda persiste o erro. por algum motivo, ele não seleciona o resto dos checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo exemplo com o seu próprio código, o mesmo funcionou perfeitamente.

Para complementar seu código adicionei uma verificação nas `<tr>` da `<table>`, dessa forma caso o usuário clique na linha o respectivo `checkbox` será marcado.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  //Para fins de depuração:
  console.log("Entrei aqui.");

  $("#checkMestre").click(function(){

    //Para fins de depuração:
    console.log("Checkbox mestre foi clicado!");
    
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  //Função para marcar o checkbox ao clicar na linha:
  $("#exemplo tr").on("click", function(){
    $(this).children().children()[0].click();
  });

  //Impeço a propagação para não dar conflito com o click na tr.
  $("input:checkbox").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="exemplo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkMestre"/>
      </th>
      <th>
        Nome
      </th>
      <th>
        Nível
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="idUsuario" value="1"/>
      </td>      
      <td>
        Caique
      </td>
      <td>
        Prata
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="idUsuario" value="2"/>
      </td>      
      <td>
        Natane
      </td>
      <td>
        Ouro
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado Caique, entretanto ainda não rolou.. ainda continuo selecionando só 1 checkbox invés de todos...

Comment: O problema persistiu, estou achando que pode ser alguma coisa do bootstrap

Comment: no head só estão as bibliotecas e o script jquery...

Comment: Caique, foi minha primeira ideia, alterei, mas não surtiu efeito.

Comment: Fiz a alteração, mas não chamou nenhum alert

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está correto e funcional. O problema é que você está carregando o evento de clique antes do PHP renderizar os elementos da tabela.

É necessário que o evento seja carregado após o DOM estar pronto. Para isso inclua o código dentro do evento `ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#checkTodos").click(function(){
      $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
   });
});
```

Você também pode colocar o script *inline* direto na tag com o evento `onclick`, aí não precisa do `$(document).ready`:

```
<input onclick="$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);" type="checkbox" id="checkTodos">
```

Comment: Fiz a inclusão do $(document).ready(function(){} conforme informado, entretanto o problema persiste. 
Sera que tem alguma coisa a ver por usar o bootstrap estar escondendo as outras checkbox checadas?

Comment: coloca um alert("ok"); dentro do evento do clique para ver se ele aparece.

Comment: Não apareceu, então não esta havendo a conexão do checkbox com o jquery

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas deixa o document ready como está

Comment: Altera o evento para isso: `$(document).on("click", "#checkTodos", function(){`

Comment: Alterei, mas não mudou, ainda não exibiu o alerta de ok

Comment: ele faz a chamada por meio do ID correto? vou alterar o ID e testar

Comment: Não vai adiantar nao... remove todos os plugins e bibliotecas, tudo, deixa só a do jQuery `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: A princípio posso afirmar com certeza que o problema é o da minha resposta mesmo, sem o document ready o clique não funciona porque o evento é carregado antes do HTML da tabela... a não ser que vc colocasse o script depois, mas não precisa....

Comment: Faz o seguinte: pega esse mesmo arquivo warningview.php que vc me mandou e salva na área de trabalho e muda a extensão de .php para .html e abra no navegador... a página vai abrir toda quebrada mas não tem problema... vai lá onde está o checkbox e teste.

Comment: Tudo bem, irei testar aqui, e ja trago a resposta.

Comment: Realmente, traz a pagina toda quebrada haha, mas funcionou, esta selecionando os check

Comment: Faz o seguinte, agora lá na sua página PHP mesmo: apaga todo esse código que estamos vendo (`$("#checkTodos").click(function(){...`) e coloca direto na tag o onclick, assim: `<input onclick="$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);" type="checkbox" id="checkTodos">`

Comment: Fiz a alteração, mas não ocorreu mudanças

Comment: Apaguei todo o script do jquery e adicionei esta linha onde ficaria o checkbox mesmo, seria esse o procedimento?

Comment: Ficou assim? `<input onclick="$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);" type="checkbox" id="checkTodos">`

Comment: isso, ficou assim

Comment: Blz... vou alterar para JS puro.. perai

Comment: tentei fazer através de um botão mesmo por uma function de JS puro, mas tbm não rolou... eu acho que alguma coisa bloqueia o comando ou a passagem de informação para o JS

Comment: testa aí: `<input onclick="var els=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');for(var x=0;x<els.length;x++){els[x].checked=this.checked;}" type="checkbox" id="checkTodos">`

Comment: Ainda nada, cara isso ta me deixando meio cabreiro... não tem motivo pra não funcionar, não acusa nenhum erro, e quando convertido para html funciona.

Comment: pode ser problema no servidor mesmo

Comment: vc tá usando servidor local na própria máquina ou está hospedado?

Comment: To usando local, utilizo o wamp

Answer (score 0):

Alteração no input `checkbox`:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" value='.$codigo.' name="check[]" class="check"/></td>
```

No `Jquery`:

```
$('#checkMaster').click(function(){
    $.each($('.check'),function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
      }else{
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Opa, irei testar esse jeito