# como ficaria a function para habilitar varios checkbox apartir de um type Radio

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radiobutton

Gostaria de fazer checkbox de redes sociais, mas que só habilite se a pessoa clicar no type="radio" "sim". como ficaria a function para isso no javascript.

```
    <label>Possui rede social: </label>
    <input type="radio" name ="social" onclick="habilitar" id="1" > Sim
    <input type="radio" name="social"                      id="2" > Nao <br><br>
    <label>Quais</label><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="facebook"  disabled> facebook<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="linkedin"  disabled> linkedin<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="instagram" disabled> instagram<br>
```

Comment: já viu as perguntas relacionadas aqui no site, por exemplo essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292060/selecionar-todos-checkbox-ao-clicar-em-um-checkbox ?

Comment: dessa forma nao funciona, preciso que apenas habilite, nao que dê checked automatico.

Comment: Na sua funcao "habilitar", voce pode remover o atributo "disabled" dos input[checkbox]. Ex: `element.removeAttribute("disabled");`. Mais info aqui [MDN - RemoveAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/element/removeAttribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque values em cada radiobutton. Será útil caso você for submeter ao servidor e útil para usar no script para diferenciar um elemento do outro (não precisa usar `id` que é desnecessário pra isso):

```
<input type="radio" name ="social" value="sim"> Sim
<input type="radio" name="social" value="nao" checked> Nao
```

No primeiro coloque `value="sim"` e no segundo `value="nao"`.

> Já que os checkbox já são carregados desabilitados, é interessante
>   também adicionar o atributo `checked` na opção "Nao", para ela já vir marcada.

É bom também colocar uma classe em cada `checkbox` para poder criar um grupo e não confundir com outros checkbox que podem ter na página:

```
<input class="social" type="checkbox" name="facebook"  disabled> facebook<br>
<input class="social" type="checkbox" name="linkedin"  disabled> linkedin<br>
<input class="social" type="checkbox" name="instagram" disabled> instagram<br>
```

Com isso, basta criar um evento `onchange` para cada radiobutton e alterar os checkbox de acordo com o value do radio alterado:

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll("[name='social']");
const social = document.querySelectorAll(".social");

for(let i of radios){
   i.onchange = function(){
      for(let x of social){
         x.disabled = i.value == "sim" ? false : true;
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<label>Possui rede social: </label>
<input type="radio" name ="social" value="sim"> Sim
<input type="radio" name="social" value="nao" checked> Nao <br><br>
<label>Quais</label><br><br>
<input class="social" type="checkbox" name="facebook"  disabled> facebook<br>
<input class="social" type="checkbox" name="linkedin"  disabled> linkedin<br>
<input class="social" type="checkbox" name="instagram" disabled> instagram<br>
```

Comment: mt obrigado manooo, vlw ajudou mt aqui, estou iniciando nessa area da programaçao e estava em duvidas em como faria o script

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você deve alterar os IDs do radio button:
Para Sim e Nao

```
<label>Possui rede social: </label>
<input type="radio" name ="social" 
id="Sim" > Sim
<input type="radio" name="social"                     id="Nao" > Nao <br><br>
<label>Quais</label><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="facebook"  disabled> facebook<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="linkedin"  disabled> linkedin<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="instagram" disabled> instagram<br>
```

JS

```
const redeS = document.querySelector("#Sim")
const redeN = document.querySelector("#Nao")
const checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')

redeS.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(redeS.checked)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
    {
      checks[i].removeAttribute("disabled")
    }
  }
})

redeN.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(redeN.checked)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
    {
      checks[i].setAttribute("disabled", "false")
    }
  }
})
```