# Ao clicar em um checkbox, marcar automaticamente outros checkboxs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<input type="radio" name="Tipo" value="Sabonete"> Sabonete<br>
<input type="radio" name="TipoSabonete" value="Neutro"> Neutro<br>
<input type="radio" name="TipoSabonete" value="Phebo"> Phebo<br>
<input type="radio" name="TipoSabonete" value="Dove"> Dove<br>

<hr>

<input type="radio" name="Tipo" value="Informatica"> Informática<br>
<input type="radio" name="TipoInformatica" value="Notebook"> Notebook<br>
<input type="radio" name="TipoInformatica" value="Desktop"> Desktop<br>
<input type="radio" name="TipoInformatica" value="Tablets"> Tablets<br>

<hr>

<input type="radio" name="Tipo" value="Smartphones"> Smartphones<br>
<input type="radio" name="TipoSmartphones" value="LG"> LG<br>
<input type="radio" name="TipoSmartphones" value="Samsung"> Samsung<br>
<input type="radio" name="TipoSmartphones" value="Nokia"> Nokia<br>
```

Gostaria que o usuário ao selecionar o Sabonete, todos os campos ligados ao Sabonete ficassem marcados, o mesmo para o item Informática e Smartphones. Vi que aqui teve uma pergunta parecida, mas sou leigo em jquery e estou com dificuldades de entender os exemplos aplicados nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292060/selecionar-todos-checkbox-ao-clicar-em-um-checkbox). Inclui somente 03 exemplos, o sistema terá na verdade mais itens.

Comment: Seria interessante se nesse site tivesse a opção da pessoa que está negativando a pergunta colocar o motivo, pois do jeito que está, dá-se a entender que essa pessoa não sabe a resposta e com isso é mais cômodo negativar do que ajudar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro ponto bem importante, você está trabalhando com `input` do tipo `radio` e não `checkbox`, logo você não vai conseguir selecionar mais de um.

---

Alterando seus inputs para `checkbox`, você consegue utilizar do `querySelectorAll`, efetuando um filtro que traga os elementos que você deseja marcar, veja exemplo abaixo:

```js
function marcarTodos(radio) {
  const itens = document.querySelectorAll(`[name$=${radio.value}]`);

  for(item of itens) {
    item.checked = radio.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="marcarTodos(this)" name="Tipo" value="Sabonete"> Sabonete<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="TipoSabonete" value="Neutro"> Neutro<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="TipoSabonete" value="Phebo"> Phebo<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="TipoSabonete" value="Dove"> Dove<br>

<hr>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="marcarTodos(this)" name="Tipo" value="Informatica"> Informática<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="TipoInformatica" value="Notebook"> Notebook<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="TipoInformatica" value="Desktop"> Desktop<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="TipoInformatica" value="Tablets"> Tablets<br>

<hr>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="marcarTodos(this)" name="Tipo" value="Smartphones"> Smartphones<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="TipoSmartphones" value="LG"> LG<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="TipoSmartphones" value="Samsung"> Samsung<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="TipoSmartphones" value="Nokia"> Nokia<br>
```

Nesse exemplo, criei uma função no `onclick` para os inputs que vão marcar os demais, aproveito o `value` para efetuar a busca com o `querySelectorAll`, buscando todos os elementos que terminam com tal valor.

---

> Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Obrigado Daniel. Funcionou perfeitamente!!!